# What type of pointer should I return from static member method

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, static-methods, static-members

I come mostly from the world of Java, but have recently been writing a bunch of c++ and still don't have a great understanding of how to use pointers or what type of pointers to use where. I will give a brief example of my case, and keep in mind the question I am really asking is, "What type of pointer should I use and why?".

A perfect parallel to my code is to consider a class for a chain link. Each link has a parent link, except for the root link of which there can only be 1.

```cpp
// Link.hpp
class Link
{
public:
    Link(const std::string &linkName, Link *parentLink);
    Link(const std::string &linkNam);
    static Link* createRootLink(const std::string &linkName);
    static Link* getRootLink();

private:
    static Link *rootLink;
    Link *parentLink;
}

//Link.cpp
Link* Link::rootLink = Link::createRootLink("root");

Link* Link::createRootLink(const std::string &linkName);
{
    // Is raw pointer correct here or should I 
    // use a different pointer type, i.e. smart_pointer, 
    // shared_pointer, etc?
    Link *rootLink = new Link(linkName); 
    return rootLink;
}

Link* getRootLink()
{
     return rootLink;
}

Link::Link(const std::string &linkName)
{
    this->linkName = linkName;
    this->parentLink = NULL; // Root link has no parent link.
}

Link::Link(const std::string &linkName, Link *parentLink)
{
    this->linkName = linkName;
    this->parentLink = parentLink;
}
```

Hopefully this is clear enough. I Java this type of thing is simple, but in c++ I am not sure how to manage the need for pointers to static objects. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Your `Link::createRootLink()` probably was intended to return that new value.

Comment: Regarding your commented question, raw pointer is wrong, it says to the reader of the code "no need to `delete` this pointer". You should use `unique_ptr` there, it says "I am responsible for `delete`ing this pointer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this (as it is inlinable in the header):

```
class Link
{
public:
    Link(const std::string &linkName, Link *parentLink);
    Link(const std::string &linkNam);
    static Link* getRootLink() {
        static std::unique_ptr<Link> root(new Link("root"));
        return root.get();
    }
};
```

In a single threaded environment this is fine, in multithreaded you'll need to protect against multiple threads accessing `getRootLink` at the same time for the very first time (there's a guard pattern to enable this.)

Note the `unique_ptr` is there to allow the deconstructor to run at the end of your programme. If you know you don't need the deconstructor, a plain old pointer is fine too.

Comment: From C++11, static local variables like this are thread safe (although not all compilers are compliant yet so it is best to check).

Comment: @BeyelerStudios consider the case where getRootLink() is called hundreds of times per second. It looks to me like each time getRootLink() you are creating a new pointer rather than creating the pointer to the root link once?

Comment: @jlack `getRootLink` only returns the pointer to the statically instantiated `std::unique_ptr<Link> root` - only in the very first call to `getRootLink` will a new `Link` be created. Without the `static` keyword, you'd be right though (and run into other problems ^^.)

Answer (score 2):

A `Link*` is fine, and it does not matter that there happens to be exactly one for the class (`static`) -- it's still just a pointer to a `Link` object.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest returning a `std::unique_pointer<Link>` or `std::shared_pointer<Link>` or (before C++11) `std::auto_ptr<Link>`.

You can return raw pointers but you will have to manage the pointers (and lifetime of the objects they point to) separately.   Since Java does that cleanup for you - and Java developers often encourage you not to worry about such things - you will often not have the mindset to manage such things sensibly.

Comment: In changing the implementation to use `std::unique_ptr<Link>`, I am not able to return the static `std::unique_ptr<Link>` from the static method `Link::getRootLink()`. How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it is returning a pointer at all. I would expect `createRootLink()` to return by-value and `getRootLink()` to return a reference.

```
class Link
{
public:
    Link(const std::string& name, Link& parent) : name(name), parent(&parent) {}
    Link(const std::string& name) : name(name), parent(nullptr) {}

    static Link createRootLink(const std::string& name)
    {
        return Link(name);
    }

    static Link& getRootLink() 
    {
         static Link rootLink = createRootLink("root");
         return rootLink;
    }

private:
    std::string name;
    Link *parent;
};
```

Comment: This is not correct I don't think because everytime you call getRootLink() you are getting a new instance of Link? It seems to me the class Link needs to have a static member variable that is a pointer to the root link.

Comment: @jlack No, the `rootLink` local variable in `getRootLink` is static so there is only one. So, `getRootLink` will return a reference to the same `Link` every time. You could achieve the same thing with a static member variable (it doesn't need to be a pointer) but a static local variable is easier.